# Actionbarsherlock navigation_mode_list list not appearing

Tags: android, android-fragments

As My title of the question suggest, I have a SherlockFragmentActivity where I'm using the NavigationMode: NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST

However, I can't see the list to change between the items until I rotate the screen to landscape, and then it appears. And then you can rotate back to portrait to make it show.

How do I get it to show without having to rotate the screen first.

Here is my activity oncreate:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
            tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
            tintManager.setTintColor(Color.parseColor("#424254"));
            tintManager.setNavigationBarTintEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            title = new String[] {"List 1"};
            subtitle = new String[]{"List 1 sub"};
            icon = new int[]{R.drawable.list_one};
            adapter = new NavListAdapter(this, title, subtitle, icon);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

            ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navlistener = new OnNavigationListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId) {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();

                    switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag1);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag2);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag3);
                        break;
                    }
                    ft.commit();
                    return true;
                }

            };
            getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navlistener);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to Add the following lines of code just before the navlistener:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag1);
ft.commit();
```